# Шифрование пароля в python, так же как в wordpress с шифрованием md5 + соли

Tags: python, wordpress, шифрование, md5

Есть полный доступ к сайту. То есть ключи в wp-config могу подтянуть к python. Пишу программу на python, в ней пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль, далее мне нужно проверить их на правильность. В начале на уровне отладки всё сделал с помощью md5, однако когда перестало внезапно всё работать, я понял что wordpress шифрует более хитро.

Необходимо защифровать введённый пароль точно так же как шифрует его wordpress, для корректной проверки. Вычитал что вордпресс использует phpass, нашёл соотвествующее решение - https://github.com/exavolt/python-phpass/blob/master/test.py. Но оно шифрует не так, как wordpress. Как поддятнуть нужные соли из wp-config(могу их напрямую прописывать в программу, это не проблема) и зашифровать введённый пароль в хэш, точно так же как делает это wordpress.

Возможно я заморочился и есть оператор в одну строчку для шифрования подобной технологией?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ты идешь не тем путем. [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710). Тебе не нужно проверять хеш  пароля. Тебе нужно работать с ВП из твоего софта. А для этого у ВП есть масса разного АПИ.

Comment: @SeVlad Спасибо, вы помогли! )

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено на прямую через проверку на wordpress, спасибо [SeVlad](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/233741/sevlad) за философию в нужном направлении)

```py
import requests
s = requests.Session()
data = {"log": self.login, "pwd": self.password} # Передаю переменные, с логином и паролем
url = "http://wordpress-sait.com/wp-login.php"
r = s.post(url, data=data)

massiv_cokies = s.cookies
kol_vo_cokies = len(massiv_cokies)

# -------- Проверяем ввод данных -------#
if kol_vo_cokies <= 3:
  QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Не верные пароль и логин',
                            'Пароль и логин не совпадают!')
```

Почему именно kol_vo_cokies <= 3 ? .. Дело в том что при логине выдаёт 6 массивных данных(в том числе куки с логином) при неверных данных выдаёт 3 массивных данных

Comment: Что-то не то ты придумал ;) "масса разного АПИ" это вот https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs. Для работы внешнего ПО с ВП как правило используется REST-api https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/. В частности для аутентификации https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/